# Block Linux read(2) until all of count bytes have arrived

Tags: c, linux, file, system-calls, blocking

I'm using `read (2)` to read from a file (`/dev/random`, where data arrives very slowly).

However, read() returns after reading only a few bytes, while I'd like it to wait until the specified amount of bytes has been read (or an error has occurred), so the return value should always be count, or -1.

Is there any way to enable this behaviour? The `open (2)` and `read (2)` manpages do not contain any useful information on that topic, nor have I found any information regarding the topic on the Internet.

I am fully aware of the workaround of just putting the `read()` inside a while loop and calling it until all data has been read. I'd just like to know if this can be achieved in a proper way that yields deterministic behaviour and involves only O(1) syscalls, instead of the nondeterministic O(n) in case of the while loop solution.

The following minimal example reproduces the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
        int fd = open("/dev/random", 0);

        char buf[128];
        size_t bytes = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));

        printf("Bytes read: %lu\n", bytes); //output is random, usually 8.

        close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While read can be interrupted by a signal before the requested data is received, it cannot really be done without while.

You have to check the return value and count bytes, unfortunately.
And yes, the easiest way would be to write a wrapping function.

Comment: +1 and since this is `/dev/random` anyway... a few extra read calls is not going to slow you down any.

Answer (score 3):

As everyone has said,

- There's no way to guarantee that 128 bytes of randomness are available before your read returns, and
- The overhead involved in getting eight bytes at a time is trivial compared to the amortized cost of generating the eight bytes; consequently,
- You should remember that entropy comes at a huge cost and take that into account when consuming it.

Nonetheless, no answer to this question would be complete without noting that in `man 4 random` (on a vaguely recent Linux distro) you should find the following information:

```
The files in the directory /proc/sys/kernel/random
(present since 2.3.16) provide an additional interface
to the /dev/random device.
```

...

```
The file read_wakeup_threshold contains the number of bits of
entropy required for waking up processes that sleep waiting
for entropy from /dev/random. The default is 64.
```

That is, 64 *bits*, which is eight bytes. With superuser privileges you could increase this value, but imho increasing it to 1024 and then expecting your machine to keep working as normal is probably pretty optimistic. I don't know all the things that want a bit of entropy but I've certainly noticed that my entropy pool goes up and down, so I know something wants it and I strongly suspect that whatever something that is would not be happy having to wait for 1024 bits of it to be available. Anyway, you know have a bit of rope...

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, /dev/random does its best to return the most relibale randomized data it can, and that limits the number of bytes it returns in one read.

But reading /dev/urandom (notice the 'u') will return as much data as you requested (buffer size), with sometimes less randomized data.

Here is [an useful link](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl4_urandom.htm)

About the read() behavior, I'm quite sure this cannot be changed : read() returns the amount of data that the underlying plumbery (for example disk+driver+...) decided to return, it's a by-design behavior. The way to do things is, as you said, to loop until you received as much data as expected.

Comment: Is this reliable? `read` can be interrupted by a signal, will the type of a source guarantee that no such signal will arrive before the end of the call?

Comment: I require true random data. Also, I don't think it's guaranteed that a read from `/dev/urandom` will always read `count` bytes, it's just more probable.

Comment: I think that yes, it's guaranteed. Anyway, if you want the data to be as random as possible, you will have to use /dev/random AND loop until reaching the number of bytes you want. I'm sorry, but I really, really think you cannot force read() to return as much data as you want.

Comment: Yep, `urandom` is theoretically not that random as `random` ;-)